# Sending Gmail with smtp in Go

Tags: go, smtp, gmail

I was able to send email with gmail via smtp before, but not anymore. I am still able to send from localhost on my computer on Windows where I develop, but not from the production server. I have enabled "Allow less secure apps" with my gmail account. But still this is the error I get:

```
2016/06/07 10:27:03 534 5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtq
5.7.14 ZHRyO8gjNXDZjjls6t7JWkP7y1UM8Jc44oPvw0dXO96SljvNT3d2QDMlJAT3X7p4teLYY1
5.7.14 zj9NBwLOytlrdRXkjm7BZNWpPLLscyxEOUcyLL3EFHdnYiq_1P_PwQVcLvZlVGUdChm_
5.7.14 6BIdD9uJLkOOG_6b6oXyJ1YfZJneoM8IiUYlWaecNECJQYF8WLYY3hSCCnNDazjJuRvjbH
5.7.14 yqJu4xBfx-929yDQwvPmuVxL4bQv8> Please log in via your web browser and
5.7.14 then try again.
5.7.14  Learn more at
5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 89sm7243327qth.2 - gsmtp
```

[image]

It says that It has detected "an unknown device" which is the production server, but there is NO WAY for me to confirm that that device is legit. How am I supposed to send emails?

This is the code I have written to send emails, note that it works when I send from localhost on my Windows development environment, just not from the production server.

```
type Mail struct {
    Hostname   string
    Port       string
    User       string
    Password   string
    Header     map[string]string
    IsHTML     bool
    Subject    string
    Body       string
    Recipients []string
}

func New() *Mail {
    return &Mail{
        Hostname: cfg.MailHost,
        Port:     cfg.MailPort,
        User:     cfg.MailUser,
        Password: cfg.MailPass,
        Header:   map[string]string{},
        IsHTML:   true,
    }
}

func (m *Mail) AddHeader(key, value string) {
    m.Header[key] = value
}

func (m *Mail) AddRecipient(address string) {
    m.Recipients = append(m.Recipients, address)
    m.AddHeader("To", "<"+address+">")
}

func (m *Mail) HTML(isHTML bool) {
    m.IsHTML = isHTML
}

func (m *Mail) Send() error {

    if m.Subject == "" {
        m.Subject = "Some random subject..."
    }
    m.AddHeader("Subject", m.Subject)

    if _, ok := m.Header["From"]; !ok {
        m.AddHeader("From", cfg.MailName+" <"+cfg.MailUser+">")
    }

    if m.IsHTML {
        m.AddHeader("MIME-version", "1.0;")
        m.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\";")
    }

    body := ""
    for k, v := range m.Header {
        body += fmt.Sprintf("%s: %s\r\n", k, v)
    }
    body += "\r\n" + m.Body

    auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", m.User, m.Password, m.Hostname)

    err := smtp.SendMail(
        m.Hostname+":"+m.Port,
        auth,
        m.User,
        m.Recipients,
        []byte(body),
    )

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

I have no idea what to do now.

Some of the variables from config.go:

```
MailHost = "smtp.gmail.com"
MailPort = "587"
```

If I change the port from 587 to 465 as noted here:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

The I get the error: `"EOF"` when trying to send email from the production server.

It keeps saying I should go to "advanced settings in gmail" to whitelist IP address. But there is no advanced settings in gmail, only settings.

[image]

Comment: Are you using smtp-relay.gmail.com to send email? Did you go through [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en) page that details what servers to use for sending mail?

Comment: I'm going to be honest with you. Nothing that is on their pages is what it seems on their page! They say: "From the dashboard, go to Apps > Google Apps > Gmail > Advanced settings." Seriously, where do I even find this? None of the guidelines make sense to me, I can't find anything.

Comment: @Alex Apps is the 3x3 square grid in the top right corner of you gmail or other google apps. If you're in gmail just navigate to advanced settings. I think you should be able to white list that device from the place you took a screen shot of though I'm not exactly sure how to do it.

Comment: I only see settings in gmail, not advanced settings. And there is no place for me to whitelist ip addresses in gmail settings, or google account settings.

Comment: You are talking of sending from server, so you should be connecting to smtp.gmail.com and it allows sending mails from any IP address.

Comment: For some reason it worked after changing my gmail password. Totally random. Google or gmail didn't even ask me to do it. I read somewhere that "it might help to change password".